Node JS P2P script not connecting between terminals
I am trying to develop a p2p communication in node.js
'use strict';

const RPC = require('@hyperswarm/rpc');
const DHT = require('hyperdht');
const Hypercore = require('hypercore');
const Hyperbee = require('hyperbee');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const readline = require('readline');
const path = require('path');

const TOPIC = Buffer.from('p2p-auction-topic');

const main = async () => {
  const dbDir = process.argv[2];
  if (!dbDir) {
    console.error('Usage: node peer.js <db-directory>');
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const hcore = new Hypercore(path.join(dbDir, 'rpc-peer'));
  const hbee = new Hyperbee(hcore, { keyEncoding: 'utf-8', valueEncoding: 'json' });
  await hbee.ready();

  let dhtSeed = (await hbee.get('dht-seed'))?.value;
  if (!dhtSeed) {
    dhtSeed = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    await hbee.put('dht-seed', dhtSeed);
  } else {
    dhtSeed = Buffer.from(dhtSeed);
  }

  const dht = new DHT({
    keyPair: DHT.keyPair(new Uint8Array(dhtSeed)),
    bootstrap: [{ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30001 }]
  });
  await dht.ready();

  const rpc = new RPC({ seed: crypto.randomBytes(32), dht });
  const rpcServer = rpc.createServer();
  await rpcServer.listen();
  console.log('RPC server started listening on public key:', rpcServer.publicKey.toString('hex'));

  const peers = new Map(); // Use a Map to track peers by their public keys

  const discovery = dht.announce(TOPIC);
  discovery.on('peer', async (peer) => {
    console.log('Found peer:', peer);
    const client = rpc.connect(peer.publicKey);

    client.on('open', () => {
      console.log('Connected to peer:', peer.publicKey.toString('hex'));
      peers.set(peer.publicKey.toString('hex'), client);
      synchronizeAuctionData(client);
    });

    client.on('close', () => {
      console.log('Peer disconnected:', peer.publicKey.toString('hex'));
      peers.delete(peer.publicKey.toString('hex'));
    });

    client.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Peer connection error:', err);
      peers.delete(peer.publicKey.toString('hex'));
    });
  });

  async function synchronizeAuctionData(client) {
    const auctions = await hbee.createReadStream({ gt: 'auction:', lt: 'auction:~' });
    for await (const { key, value } of auctions) {
      const auctionId = key.split(':')[1];
      await broadcastMessageToPeer(client, {
        type: 'new-auction',
        payload: { auctionId, ...value }
      });
    }
  }

  rpcServer.on('open', (client) => {
    const clientId = client.publicKey.toString('hex');
    peers.set(clientId, client);
    client.on('close', () => {
      peers.delete(clientId);
    });
  });

  rpcServer.respond('open-auction', async (reqRaw) => {
    const req = JSON.parse(reqRaw.toString('utf-8'));
    const { auctionId, item, price } = req;

    const existingAuction = await hbee.get(`auction:${auctionId}`);
    const closedAuction = await hbee.get(`closed-auction:${auctionId}`);
    if (existingAuction || closedAuction) {
      return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Auction ID already exists' }), 'utf-8');
    }

    await hbee.put(`auction:${auctionId}`, { item, price, bids: [] });
    await broadcastMessage({ type: 'new-auction', payload: { auctionId, item, price } });
    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', message: 'Auction opened' }), 'utf-8');
  });

  rpcServer.respond('make-bid', async (reqRaw) => {
    const req = JSON.parse(reqRaw.toString('utf-8'));
    const { auctionId, bid } = req;

    const auction = await hbee.get(`auction:${auctionId}`);
    const closedAuction = await hbee.get(`closed-auction:${auctionId}`);
    if (closedAuction) {
      return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Cannot bid on a closed auction' }), 'utf-8');
    }
    if (!auction) {
      return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Auction not found' }), 'utf-8');
    }

    auction.value.bids.push(bid);
    await hbee.put(`auction:${auctionId}`, auction.value);
    await broadcastMessage({ type: 'new-bid', payload: { auctionId, bid } });
    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', message: 'Bid placed' }), 'utf-8');
  });

  rpcServer.respond('close-auction', async (reqRaw) => {
    const req = JSON.parse(reqRaw.toString('utf-8'));
    const { auctionId } = req;

    const auction = await hbee.get(`auction:${auctionId}`);
    if (!auction) {
      return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: 'Auction not found' }), 'utf-8');
    }

    await hbee.put(`closed-auction:${auctionId}`, auction.value);
    await hbee.del(`auction:${auctionId}`);
    await broadcastMessage({ type: 'closed-auction', payload: { auctionId, auction: auction.value } });
    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success', message: 'Auction closed' }), 'utf-8');
  });

  async function broadcastMessage(message) {
    console.log('Broadcasting message:', message);
    console.log('Connected peers:', Array.from(peers.keys()));
    for (const peer of peers.values()) {
      await broadcastMessageToPeer(peer, message);
    }
  }

  async function broadcastMessageToPeer(peer, message) {
    try {
      if (peer.opened) {
        await peer.request('message', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message), 'utf-8'));
      } else {
        console.warn('Peer not yet open for message:', message); // Log if peer isn't open yet
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to propagate message to peer:', error);
      peers.delete(peer.publicKey.toString('hex'));
    }
  }

  rpcServer.respond('message', async (reqRaw) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(reqRaw.toString('utf-8'));
    console.log('Received broadcast message:', message);

    if (message.type === 'new-auction') {
      await hbee.put(`auction:${message.payload.auctionId}`, {
        item: message.payload.item,
        price: message.payload.price,
        bids: []
      });
    } else if (message.type === 'new-bid') {
      const auction = await hbee.get(`auction:${message.payload.auctionId}`);
      if (auction) {
        auction.value.bids.push(message.payload.bid);
        await hbee.put(`auction:${message.payload.auctionId}`, auction.value);
      }
    } else if (message.type === 'closed-auction') {
      await hbee.put(`closed-auction:${message.payload.auctionId}`, message.payload.auction);
      await hbee.del(`auction:${message.payload.auctionId}`);
    }
  });

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.on('line', async (input) => {
    const [command, ...args] = input.split(' ');

    try {
      switch (command) {
        case 'open-auction':
          const [auctionId, item, price] = args;
          const openResult = await rpc.request(rpcServer.publicKey, 'open-auction', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ auctionId, item, price: parseFloat(price) }), 'utf-8'));
          console.log(JSON.parse(openResult.toString('utf-8')));
          break;

        case 'make-bid':
          const [auctionIdBid, bid] = args;
          const bidResult = await rpc.request(rpcServer.publicKey, 'make-bid', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ auctionId: auctionIdBid, bid: parseFloat(bid) }), 'utf-8'));
          console.log(JSON.parse(bidResult.toString('utf-8')));
          break;

        case 'close-auction':
          const [auctionIdClose] = args;
          const closeResult = await rpc.request(rpcServer.publicKey, 'close-auction', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ auctionId: auctionIdClose }), 'utf-8'));
          console.log(JSON.parse(closeResult.toString('utf-8')));
          break;

        default:
          console.log('Unknown command');
          break;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error executing command:', error.message);
    }
  });

  const cleanup = async () => {
    console.log('Closing connections...');
    await rpc.destroy();
    await dht.destroy();
    rl.close();
    process.exit(0);
  };

  process.on('SIGINT', cleanup);
  process.on('SIGTERM', cleanup);
  process.on('exit', cleanup);

  console.log('Peer ready. Enter commands: open-auction <auctionId> <item> <price>, make-bid <auctionId> <bid>, close-auction <auctionId>');

  // Periodically log the list of connected peers
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Currently connected peers:', Array.from(peers.keys()));
  }, 5000); // Log every 5 seconds
};

main().catch(console.error);

The problem is that if i open two peers in two different terminals with command node peer.js db1
and node peer.js db2, i dont see connection between both, so if i open an auction in 1 terminal, i cant make a bid in the second terminal, because there is no communication.
When i announce the topic, i dont see logs, what makes me think that can be some issue in the bootstrap, but the logs of bootstrap looks fine
What should i do to fix it?

Please try to make your reproducible example minimal, more often during the process of trying to make a minimal reproducible example you can figure out the issue yourself. Try making a simplest working program that can ping each other before adding other complicated functions. Start building up from there once you get the basic communication working.
